# fix config in .vimrc file

Tags: vim

In the .vimrc file, I've written

```
if exits(":Tabularize")
   nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /=<CR>
   nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /:<CR>
   nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /|<CR>
endif
```

However, when I quit `vim` with `:wq`, I got

```
Error detected while processing /home/jeremie/.vimrc:
line   27:
E488: Trailing characters: <CR>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How could I fix this problem?

Thanks!

**P.S** I think the only problem is with `|`, because if I put the line in comment, the problem disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a command separator.  Replace it with `<Bar>`, or escape it:

```
nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /<Bar><CR>
```

or

```
nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /\|<CR>
```